# Using Applescript to open an excel file and enable macros in MacOs

Tags: excel, applescript, applescript-excel

How can I use Applescript to open an Excel file in MacOs and enable the macros?

I have tried :

```
-- Set the path to your Excel file
set excelFile to "/Users/spagcoder/Desktop/proms webform/PROMS.xlsm"

-- Launch Excel in the background
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    delay 5
    open workbook workbook file name excelFile
    delay 3
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
    click button "Enable Macros" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

This opens the file and the but then the script just hangs when the disable/enable macros alert comes up.

If the file is already open and the macros dialog box is open, I can run a script that is just

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
    click button "Enable Macros" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

And this works. The button gets clicked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the script open an Excel file (on Mac OS), automatically enable macros and then run a macro. When I run the script, it opens the Excel file and Excel immediately pops up a dialog asking me to enable or disable macros. The script won't proceed until I click on one of the buttons. This means that it never gets to the part of the script that clicks the button programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior as you in testing: selecting whether to enable or disable macros is part of the 'open' process for an .xlsm, so runtime stalls until you make a selection.

You can work around this by shifting your second delay period into a timeout wrapped inside a try instead:

```
try
    with timeout of 3 seconds
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            activate
            delay 5
            open excelFile
            --delay 3
        end tell
    end timeout
on error msg number num
    if num = -1712 then
        #Apple Event timed out. Keep processing.
    else
        #if anything else caused the error:
        error msg number num
    end if
end try
```

Sorry if this is too late to help for your project.  This question was google's top result when I came looking for inspiration to accomplish same thing, though, so hopefully it might be of use to others also stumbling across it.